# How can I see roles permissions in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

Is there a way to view all permissions added to a specific role in SQL Server ?

When looking at role's "properties" in SSMS, I only see schemas owned by the role.
In the case where we can't see it using the GUI, is there a system view to call ?

**EDIT :**
To be more precise, I want to be able to see all rights corresponding to an existing role in a database like "db_owner" for example.

Comment: How about http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2007/02/09/SQL-Server-2005_3A00_-View-all-permissions--_2800_2_2900_.aspx

Comment: It doesn't correspond to my need. I want roles permissions, not users permissions.

Comment: Did you check this one? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36618/list-all-permissions-for-a-given-role

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the sys. and try to do it
below a example:

```
WITH    perms_cte as
(
        select USER_NAME(p.grantee_principal_id) AS principal_name,
                dp.principal_id,
                dp.type_desc AS principal_type_desc,
                p.class_desc,
                OBJECT_NAME(p.major_id) AS object_name,
                p.permission_name,
                p.state_desc AS permission_state_desc
        from    sys.database_permissions p
        inner   JOIN sys.database_principals dp
        on     p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
)
--users
SELECT p.principal_name,  p.principal_type_desc, p.class_desc, p.[object_name], p.permission_name, p.permission_state_desc, cast(NULL as sysname) as role_name
FROM    perms_cte p
WHERE   principal_type_desc <> 'DATABASE_ROLE'
UNION
--role members
SELECT rm.member_principal_name, rm.principal_type_desc, p.class_desc, p.object_name, p.permission_name, p.permission_state_desc,rm.role_name
FROM    perms_cte p
right outer JOIN (
    select role_principal_id, dp.type_desc as principal_type_desc, member_principal_id,user_name(member_principal_id) as member_principal_name,user_name(role_principal_id) as role_name--,*
    from    sys.database_role_members rm
    INNER   JOIN sys.database_principals dp
    ON     rm.member_principal_id = dp.principal_id
) rm
ON     rm.role_principal_id = p.principal_id
```

also there's this system SP

```
exec sp_helprole
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it doesn't correspond to my need. (like I said to DNac).